# How to get the next instance of an "ENDIF" string for if statement in custom language

Tags: python, interpreter

I am making a custom language and writing it in Python. I have if statements with number equalities and inequalities, but I´m having trouble implementing the conditional execution of the code in the if statement block. Here's my code for the tokenizer of if statements:

```
elif tok == "IF":
        tokens.append("IF")
        tok = ""        
    elif tok == "THEN":
        if expr != "" and isexpr == 0:
            tokens.append("NUM:" + expr)
            expr = ""
        tokens.append("THEN")
        tok = ""
```

I also use a string, "ENDIF", to end the if statement. Essentially, the "THEN" is the opening bracket and "ENDIF" is the closing bracket, if this was a language that used brackets.

The parser for int eq/ineq if statements:

```
elif toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] + " " + toks[i+2] + " " + toks[i+3][0:3] + " " + toks[i+4] == "IF NUM LESSTHAN NUM THEN":
        if toks[i+1][4:] < toks[i+3][4:]:
            print("TRUE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is less than " + toks[i+3][4:])
        else:
            print("TRUE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is not less than " + toks[i+3][4:])
        i += 5
    elif toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] + " " + toks[i+2] + " " + toks[i+3][0:3] + " " + toks[i+4] == "IF NUM MORETHAN NUM THEN":
        if toks[i+1][4:] > toks[i+3][4:]:
            print("TRUE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is greater than " + toks[i+3][4:])
        else:
            print("FALSE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is not greater than " + toks[i+3][4:])
        i += 5
    elif toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] + " " + toks[i+2] + " " + toks[i+3][0:3] + " " + toks[i+4] == "IF NUM LESSOREQUAL NUM THEN":
        if toks[i+1][4:] <= toks[i+3][4:]:
            print("TRUE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is less than or equal to " + toks[i+3][4:])
        else:
            print("FALSE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is not less than or equal to " + toks[i+3][4:])
        i += 5
    elif toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] + " " + toks[i+2] + " " + toks[i+3][0:3] + " " + toks[i+4] == "IF NUM MOREOREQUAL NUM THEN":
        if toks[i+1][4:] >= toks[i+3][4:]:
            print("TRUE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is greater than or equal to " + toks[i+3][4:])
        else:
            print("FALSE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is not greater than or equal to " + toks[i+3][4:])
        i += 5
    elif toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] + " " + toks[i+2] + " " + toks[i+3][0:3] + " " + toks[i+4] == "IF NUM NOTEQUAL NUM THEN":
        if toks[i+1][4:] != toks[i+3][4:]:
            print("TRUE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is not equal to " + toks[i+3][4:])
        else:
            print("FALSE, " + toks[i+1][4:] + " is equal to " + toks[i+3][4:])
        i += 5
```

here's an example of an if statement in my language:

```
IF 1 == 2 THEN
     OUT "Hello, world!"
ENDIF
```

Obviously, that will return false, but it still prints Hello World as of now, because I don't know how to skip the code if it returns false... I was thinking of skipping to the next endif in the file... I think I know how to do it though. I just need to find the place of the token in the tokens[] array... if I can do that, then I can set the iterator variable past the ENDIF. Is there a function that will let me search an array for the next appearance of a string after a certain place (for example, tokens[4:]), then return the index value of that element in the array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Writing parsers is not trivial. The way you handle it you'll soon have a very large, unmanageable code base. Try to write functions that evaluate expressions, so your `IF` validates what comes after it as an expression. For pairing `IF` with `ENDIF` think of nesting, and thus recursion, or at least a stack.

Comment: @trincot Thanks, I never thought of nesting... Anyways, for right now all I'm worried about is getting this part to work. I'll worry about nesting and stuff later, and eventually I'll break it all up into separate files and stuff

Comment: An alternative thought would be to spend the time to learn python-ply (python-lex-yacc). lex and yacc have been in use for 40+? years and `ply` is a python implementation of it.  Yes, it's hard, but rather than inventing your own, you might learn a re-usable skill!

Comment: @pbuck I have been recommended things like that, as well as ANTLR, however I don't intend for this to be a useful language. It's just a project to learn how to make an interpreter, and I'd like to actually program it myself. I'll definitely look into python-ply though, so thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! 
While it is very primitive and doesn't support nesting (yet), I have a simple solution to my problem. Basically, whenever it detects the 'IF' token, it loops through all of the tokens after that until it finds and 'ENDIF' token. While doing that, it increments an iterator called 'ii' and at the end, sets the main iterator past the 'ENDIF', ignoring the code within the if statement. This is only done if the condition parser returns false.

code:

```
def doIF_FALSE(tokens):
    ii = 0
    for token in tokens:
        if token == "IF":
            ii = 1
        elif token == "ENDIF":
            ii += 1
            break
        else:
            ii += 1
    return ii
```

for the call, I set the iterator value like this: `i = doIF_FALSE(tokens[i:])`

Example code:

```
IF 1 > 2 THEN
     OUT "1 is greater than 2"
ENDIF

OUT "You passed the if statement"
```

Output:

```
"You passed the if statement"
```

NOTE: Yes, I realize that this is the same answer as another question I asked, but they're basically the same question...